# Can you post process results from Cloud ML's prediction output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have a model for object detection (Faster RCNN from Tensorflow's Object Detection API) running on Google Cloud ML. I also have some code to filter the resulting bounding boxes based on size, aspect ratio etc.

1. Is it possible to run this code as part of the prediction process so I don't need to run a separate process to do it afterwards.
2. Is it possible to limit the number of bounding boxes predicted by the model based on some confidence threshold, as currently outputting a lot of extraneous data.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can simply add your filter logic to prediction process code and deploy it back.
2. Yes you can use **min_score_thresh** argument in **visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array**. use below code

> ```
> vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
>         image_np,
>         np.squeeze(boxes),
>         np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
>         np.squeeze(scores),
>         category_index,
>         use_normalized_coordinates=True,
>         line_thickness=4,
>         min_score_thresh=.9)
> ```

This will result in bounding boxes with more than or equal to 90% confidence score. change it to any value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer (1): we have an Alpha API that will permit this. Please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com for more information.